# Show $x$-coordinate of stationary point satisfy the equation $x=\frac32+ \frac{x}{e^{2x}}$

Tags: numerical-methods, stationary-point

I solved the equation but when it satisfies it spouse to have opposite signs i think  this is the question

> **Question 1** The curve with equation $y=\dfrac{e^{2x}+x}{x^3}$ has a stationary point with $x$-coordinate lying between $1$ and $2$.
>
> a. Show that the $x$-coordinate of this stationary point satisfies the equation $x=\dfrac32+\dfrac{x}{e^{2x}}$.
>
> b. Using a suitable iterative process based on the qeuation given in **part a**, find the value of the $x$-coordinate of this stationary point correct to 4 decimal places.  Give each iteration to 6 decimal places.

the question is 1a this is my working out. I have no teacher cso any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.
[image]

Comment: You have used the quotient rule incorrectly, if that's what you were trying to do.

Comment: Hi mary, I have replied to your email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$y = \frac{e^{2x} + x}{x^3} = \frac{e^{2x}}{x^3} + \frac{x}{x^3} = e^{2x} x^{-3} + x^{-2}$. Thus you can just use the product rule:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 0 \Rightarrow e^{2x} \cdot -3x^{-4} + 2e^{2x} \cdot x^{-3} - 2x^{-3} = 0$$

$$\Rightarrow e^{2x} \cdot -3 + 2e^{2x} \cdot x - 2x = 0$$

then divide both sides by $e^{2x}$.

Comment: I see what you did i had to use the product rule. Thank you very much!

Comment: Well, it wouldn't be wrong to say if you had used the quotient rule, but it would just take more steps, and applying the quotient rule without separating the $x^{-2}$ out first would be horrendous. Why not make your life easier with the product rule?

Comment: I find that I make fewer mistakes when there are fewer steps to complete: for a first-time learner, it must be confusing differentiating between $uv' + u'v$ in the product rule and $uv' - uv'$ in the numerator of the quotient rule.